# How to send back a JWT token with HttpURLConnection in java?

Tags: java, web-services, httpurlconnection, json-web-token

I am using an API to get some information. At the beginning of each session you need to get a JWT token to be able to send requests to the API. After I've got the token and I try to send a request, I get an error saying I'm unauthorized, which is fair since I did not attach the token in my request. The problem is that the documentation for the API does not explain how to do this, and I haven't been able to find it anywhere else either. How do I do this? I am doing this is Java and is using their own HttpURLConnection. Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: @eckes Thank you verry much, that worked perfectly. I figured it would be something in the header, but I couldn't figure out the key. Not important, but why is the "Bearer " required?

Comment: Turned it into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the web-service (API) wants to have the token represented.

Common are:

- HTTP request headers (problem for XHR requests)
- query parameters (bad idea because of caching/logging)
- form fields (not universally useable)
- URL segment (bad idea because of caching/logging)
- certain cookies with the token as value (transparent) or
- authentication header (typical)

The Authentication headers as defined in HTTP RFCs are typically be used with the `Basic` or `Digest` authorization scheme. In case a string (token) authenticates the bearer of that token, the "Bearer" scheme is used (for example defined for OAuth2 in RFC6750).

You would use

```
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer " + jwt);
```

for this.